# How to convert varchar2 column containing decimal numbers to number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column named discount of type varchar2. It contains decimal numbers as well as integers. I want to convert it into number type. So I used this query

```
update table_name set newdiscount=to_number(discount)
```

I am getting the "Not a valid number" error. Here new discount is of type number.

I checked if there are any commas present, but they aren't. Of course, there are many rows containing decimal points which are showing up in the result of query test to check any non digit values

```
SELECT discount FROM table_name  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(discount, '[^[:digit:]]');
```

How to copy the discount values in to the newdiscount column of type number?

Answer (score 1):

Probably [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams144.htm) parameter in Oracle session differs from decimal point.

You can test it such a way:

```
select 
  substr(VALUE ,1,1) as decimal_separator,
  substr(VALUE ,2,1) as group_separator
from 
  nls_session_parameters 
where 
  parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

You can alter session before updating table to activate proper separator:

```
alter session set  NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'
```

or substitute decimal point to current decimal separator each time:

```
update table_name 
set newdiscount = ( select to_number( replace(discount, '.', substr(value,1,1)) )
                    from nls_session_parameters 
                    where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'                  
                  )
```

Some proof of concept demonstration can be found in [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12489).

Comment: No luck mate, checked the parameters, they were correct. I tried the update query which stopped after the same error. I am unable to know in which row the error is actually as the dataset is very large

Comment: You can use `merge ... log errors into ...` syntax and collect all or only the first error rows to see what caused error. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#BGBDCCEC

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating only those validates to be a numeric like,

```
update table_name
set new_discount = CASE WHEN regexp_like(discount, '^[+-]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$') THEN to_number(discount) ELSE -99999 END
```

Comment: I want everything to be numeric so that I want to perform some arithmetic operations. I certainly cannot miss some of the rows

Comment: I have updated the query - this will update with numeric value for the patterns are matching, decimal, exponential (almost all are handled here). Any non-numeric value including the null will be updated with -99999. Hope this will do the job